# Javascript popup, Php

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a javascript popup and I am stuck with the below two things,

1) I want the parent html page to be updated once the popup page updates.

2) how can i close the popup when i click on cancel

Implementation Sample :

http://www.gotit.co/pop_sample/test.php

Comment: your example is vulnerable to SQL-injection

Comment: Could you put a link to what you have so far? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @Jacco : I will set a validation of user session before inserting I just want to sort this out.

Comment: @Shai Mishali: link here http://www.gotit.co/pop_sample/test.php

Answer (score 0):

By what you showed me you could do two things 
1. When the request is successful on the "frame" thats opened, You can use an AJAX call to refresh the content of the parent with a $.post or $.ajax method call.

Also, you could, on success, just call parent.reload(); to refresh the entire page, but thats not as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

1)window.opener gives you the 'parent of your popup. Just do reload or change location;

2)to close popup: 
onclick event on your cancel button with javascript: window.close();